# Alternative to attributes in TypeWriter to allow for properties in partial classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, typewriter

The implementation of partial support is fantastic as this allows interpretation of customized scaffolded models (e.g. generate partials for the model and then use matched partials to provide customization). The only problem I have is that I used to use two attribute tags (Exclude/Include) to tune what is included in my model (per below).

This won't work with partials because you cannot modify the tags on a property in the second partial, and the scaffold obviously doesn't know where to put the tags. What alternatives are there to handle this?

I could create a JSON file with a list of the excluded/included properties in each class and load it, but I cannot parse it as no JSON libraries are natively available. I could probably use just a CSV, but this all seems clunky. Any ideas?

```
List<Property> getProperties(Class c)
{
List<string> exclProperties = new List<string>(){"CreatedOn", "ModifiedOn", "CreatedBy", "ModifiedBy", "Hrid","UniqueId","OptimisticLockField"};
List<Property> lstInclProps = new List<Property>();
bool inclColl = inclCollections(c);
foreach (Property p in c.Properties)
{
    if (PropertyAttribute(p,"Exclude",null)=="true") continue;
    if (PropertyAttribute(p,"Include",null)=="true") lstInclProps.Add(p);
    if (exclProperties.Any(x=>x.ToLower()== p.Name.ToLower())) continue;
    if (p.Type.IsEnumerable && !inclColl) continue;
    lstInclProps.Add(p);
}
return lstInclProps;
}
```